# angular js with php integration

Tags: php, angularjs

I used the code from http://angularjs.org/ (Wire up a Backend) 
Here in project.js

```
angular.module('project', ['firebase']).
 value('fbURL', 'https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com/').
 factory('Projects', function(angularFireCollection, fbURL) {
 return angularFireCollection(fbURL);
 }).
 config(function($routeProvider) {
```

I used this code in my web page. Instead of https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com/ url i want to use my url i.e http://test.com/test.php. But it didn't work.

Also i want to know in my php file in which format the out put should be?
Do you need to echo the content in php file or use the return command? Please give suggestion. I have searched a lot. I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Its not working.   angular.module('project', ['firebase']).
  value('fbURL', 'http://test.com/process.php').
  factory('Projects', function(angularFireCollection, fbURL) {
  return angularFireCollection(fbURL);
  }). Shall we need to remove firebase?

Answer (score 1):

I think in firebase url https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com/ they are returning the response from their back-end service. That is why it didn't worked for you even if you changed the `URL`.

And answer to your second question;

If you make a call to your back-end service its better to have a `json` response style from your PHP and you don't have to use any `return` command for that. Instead you should `echo` your contents.

For example in your PHP file if you are getting the results as an array you can give back the response to the `angular` application as;

```
echo json_encode($result_array);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should separate backend and frontend and treat them as two separated application. Both apps should communicate with each other by sending ajax request (front) and respone data in json format (backend). In my opinion it's the best way to handle this.